# Using TStringList in Windows with Chinese display language?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How do I make my program compatible with non English Windows region (e.g Chinese)?

My program is compiled with Delphi XE2 and it loads signature file contain some hashes.

DB.txt contains Cardinal type data:

```
5654564534
8674534664
```

I use TStringList with TEncoding.Default to load the file and store the hashes in array (Cardinal).

```
SL.LoadFromFile(Path, TEncoding.Default);
SetLength(myCardinalArray, SL.Count - 1);
for i := 1 to SL.Count - 1 do
begin
myCardinalArray[i - 1] := strtoint64(SL[i]);
end;
```

Until here, the program work properly but when the program is executed in Windows with Chinese display language, the array contained invalid hashes.

I've tried TEncoding.Unicode and others property then my program does not work in Windows with English display language! Should I detect for BOM first before use TEncoding.Unicode?

What type of encoding to make my program can run both in Windows with English and Chinese display language?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. As it stands, nothing in the question can explain any differing behaviour. Your file contains only ASCII characters and so `TEncoding.Default` is fine. Likely the issue is in the functions that convert from strings to hashes. Perhaps. But we are compelled to guess. So, provide a [mcve] and remove doubt.

Comment: `TEncoding.Default` represents the OS default Ansi codepage. While it is true that MOST Windows codepages support 7bit ASCII characters, I would not always trust that. I have run into odd codepages that don't play nice. UTF-8 by design is compatible with 7bit ASCII, so I would opt for using `TEncoding.UTF8` instead.

Comment: @Remy All Windows codepages contain 7 bit ASCII

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I used to think so too, until I started encountering situations that needed to use the EBCDIC-based codepages, which don't implement ASCII in the "normal" way. Not all byte values < $80 in EBCDIC are the same values in ASCII. For example, in cp1026, a LF is $25 instead of $0A, and $0A maps to codepoint U+008E instead of U+000A. That was breaking some of my code that read CRLF-delimited lines from streams/sockets where the CRLF was encoded using the same codepage that was used to decode the rest of the line. I had to change my code to use hard-coded $0D $0A to read the lines.

Comment: @Remy They aren't Windows code pages though. In the sense that the locale cannot be set to such code pages. As I understand it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: They are still real codepages as far as the `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions are concerned.  And at the time, my code was parsing an email that actually used cp1026 encoding and was using those functions.  But, you are right, any codepage that `TEncoding.Default` can retrieve from the OS setup should all represent 7bit ASCII the same way.

Comment: @Remy I think that's the key. For sure they are code pages that MBTWC and WCTMB understand, they aren't locale code pages. As I understand it. But I know you are much more expert than me in this field, so I tread carefully!